# Google Maps, infowindow address on multiple locations

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I wonder if anyone can help me out, I have searched this site but i haven't found an answer

my javascript is rusty if anything else, i have a js fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ux8L7beg/

What I want to do is in the infowindow popup, i want to be able to display the title for multple locations through my variable called features, i.e when you hover over glasgow, the title Glasgow showroom will appear in the infowindow, I guess I am focusing on this specific part

```
    var content = '<h3>' + "Showroom"  + features + '</h3>' + ""  

     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, content, infowindow) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        };
    })(marker, content,  infowindow));

    }
    /* add showroom locations */
    var features = [{
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(55.8511441, -4.2793418),
        type: 'showroom',
        title: 'Glasgow Showroom'
    }, {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3497877, -1.4821523),
        type: 'showroom',
        title: 'Sheffield Showroom'
    },
```

anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks
Robbie

Comment: What issue are you having with the posted code?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates that issue. I see an infowindow on each marker (that I checked) in your fiddle.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for.  Does this help?  https://jsfiddle.net/ux8L7beg/2/

Comment: Thankyou Emmanuel, that is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code a little bit to get what you need. Hope it helps you:

```js
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  var lat = locations[i].position.lat();
  var lng = locations[i].position.lng();
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    map: map,
    icon: 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-icons-24-px/24/location-24-32.png'
  });
  var prev_infowindow = false;
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      var contentString = locations[i].title;
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
      });
      if (prev_infowindow) {
        prev_infowindow.close();
      }
      prev_infowindow = infoWindow;
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

I've also removed your `addMarker` function and the `for` loop at the end and created my own.

And here is the working [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/5ed4upr0/).